# How to give an image to a submit button in html

Tags: html

at present am having a button like this

```
<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Generate Report" />
```

i have to use an image for that submit button i gave as follows

```
<input type="image" id="continue" style="float:right;"  src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_high.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png'"/>
```

if am giving type as image image is displaying but it is not working as submit button. and if am giving type as submit image is not displaying what is the wrong am doing

one more thing is that am having another button as

```
<span class="button" style="margin-left:525px;padding-top:8px;" ><a style="color: #FFFFFF;" href="add_user?height=500&width=650&modal=false" 
                            class="thickbox">Add User</a></span>
```

if am using image as above the page is not displaying as modal and it is displaying as a new page.

please someone help me thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using images inside <button> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576843/using-images-inside-button-element)

Comment: CSS would make it much easier to style, especially for states like hover, active, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image as *background for the submit button*

```
input[type=submit] {
    background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c2d133677c207759e83d86e9fca4996a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
}
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xTuNM/1/)

### Updates:

```
input[type=submit] {
    background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c2d133677c207759e83d86e9fca4996a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fdae182b503055896b55c8c567e670a3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
```

What you have asked is **`hovering`**

Check this [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xTuNM/2/)

Comment: i need to give two images one is normally shown and the other is when cursor is placed on it how to get this.

Comment: it is working thanks. what about modal why it is not working after adding image to button.

Comment: @user2739848 Modal?? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: the html psge is to be opened as a modal. but when am using the image it is opening as a total page it is not considering the height and width provided

Comment: @user2739848 you mean height of image !== button or onclick the button, it will be opening a modal which is not working now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38616/discussion-between-user1671639-and-user2739848)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try This,

```
   <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Generate Report" style="background:url(abc/in.jpg)repeat; />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="submit_style" />
```

Add this css

```
.submit_style { 
    background-image: url(http://your_image_path.jpg);
    background-position:  0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 186px;
    height: 53px;
    border: 0px;

}
```