# HTML custom (not Font-Awesome) icon class not working

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to include a custom image as an icon rather than one from Font Awesome as is usually the case. So within my HTML button, I am referencing the CSS class which contains the background image url of my local image that I would like to use as an icon. However, it is not displaying in browser. Note that all code is fully validated.

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
<input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="icon"></i>
 </button>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
background: url('../imgs/search-icon.png');
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
}
```

Fiddle:

```css
#search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon {
  background: url('https://postimg.org/image/bfac47qav/');
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="icon"></i>
     </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you upload it to some online editors at least we can see the structure.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a `background-size`, e.g: `background-size: contain`? Also, can you confirm that the filepath, for the icon in question, is valid?

Comment: I will upload to editor @PannaDas

Comment: @mts396 please share the link

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I can confirm file path is correct. I tried the background-size: contain and also other sizes, still not showing up

Comment: @PannaDas Added JSFiddle

Comment: @mts396 where is the link to your jsFiddle

Comment: @PannaDas In original post: https://jsfiddle.net/8acg8dk1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple method is to, use `content`. Don't use `background`

```css
#search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon {
  content: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/PAbELXsl2P7mE/giphy.gif");
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="icon"></i>
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest fix, replacing 'background' with 'content' does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
BUTTON {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana;   
background: #f0f0f0 url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: 8px 8px;
    }
```

fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/EFsU8/` and its solved in [using images inside <button> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576843/using-images-inside-button-element) you can check that too

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

Add the `display: block` to the class icon, As per @fbuchlak suggested the answer but you have to also check the image path.

This is not a correct path of the image

https://postimg.org/image/bfac47qav/

This is the correct path

https://s7.postimg.org/5ecn753or/search-icon.png

Below is the example

```css
#search{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}
.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}
.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.icon{
   background: url('https://s7.postimg.org/5ecn753or/search-icon.png');
   width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover; 
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="icon"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cool! Happy codding.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .searchButton {
    background: #fff url(http://pixsector.com/cache/e7836840/ave6d43d85eb121839a10.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 4%;
    height: 21px;
}



 <div id="search">
<input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
 <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
   <span class="icon"></span> 
   </button>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5tm168uk/13/